# C++ quicksort with pointers

Tags: c++, algorithm, pointers, quicksort

Can someone point out the mistake in my code? Sorry for misleading names of function arguments - rptr should be rvalue or somethings etc, I was constantly changing something. 
Most of it should be done using pointers.
I think the mistake might be in partArr, returning invalid variable, but i dont really know.

```
#include <iostream>

const int ArSize = 10;

void swap(int *lptr, int *rptr) {
    int tempV = *lptr;
    *lptr = *rptr;    
    *rptr = tempV;
}

int partArr(int *arr, int lptr, int rptr) {
    int pivot = (lptr + rptr) / 2;
    int * leftP = &lptr;
    int * rightP = &rptr;

    while (true) {
        while (arr[*rightP] >= pivot) --(*rightP);
        while (arr[*leftP] <= pivot)  ++(*leftP);
        if(*rightP > *leftP) {
            swap(leftP,rightP);
            --(*rightP);
            ++(*leftP);
        }
        else {
            return rptr;
        }
    }
}

void quickSort(int *arr, int ptrL, int ptrR) {
    if (ptrR > ptrL) { 
        int arr_piv = partArr(arr, ptrL, ptrR);    
        quickSort(arr, ptrL, arr_piv - 1);    
        quickSort(arr,arr_piv+1,ptrR);
    }
}

int main() {
    int tab[ArSize] = {10, 40, 30, 4, 3, 312, 3, 4, 1};  
    int ptrL = tab[0];    
    int ptrR = tab[ArSize - 1];
    quickSort(tab, ptrL, ptrR);
    for (int x : tab)
        std::cout << x << " ";
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: what is the problem? How do you know that there is something wrong with the code? Is there an error? Wrong output? What did you find when you used a debugger?

Comment: Ye i should have mentioned, the order of that array doesn't change at all, and  I'm currently unable to use debugger.

Comment: Why are you unable to use the debugger?

Comment: Naming your index variables "lptr" and "rptr" is confusing. They are not pointers, and the locations where they are stored are completely irrelevant.

Comment: I am using not a computer of mine, besides i thought that the mistake here is pretty obvious, so me being total noob can't see that.I am just very curious of what is wrong there.

Comment: @Mac whose computer are you using? Certainly the IDE you're developing this in has a debugger associated with it.

Comment: no IDE, Its kwrite with c++ syntax highlight. inb4 yes i know i could have used gbd but I encountered some problems with running it, due to the version not being capable of dealing with 64bits project, but just now i discovered that i can build that project in 32 bit binary so cool i can debug now.

Comment: @Mac It's not too late to mention the things you should have mentioned, nor is it too late to give your variables better names. Please edit your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here

```
int * leftP = &lptr;
int * rightP = &rptr;
```

you take the addresses of the function paramters. When you call

```
swap(leftP,rightP);
```

then you swap the values of `lptr` and `rptr`. When you write

```
--(*rightP)
```

you decrement the value of `rptr`. You never actually modify an element of the array.

I don't have a CS degree, hence when I want to sort an array I use [`std::sort`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sort):

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
int main() {
    int tab[] = {10, 40, 30, 4, 3, 312, 3, 4, 1};  

    std::sort( std::begin(tab), std::end(tab));

    for (int& x : tab)
        std::cout << x << " ";
    return 0;
}
```

If you need to implement it yourself as an exercise you should to learn how to use a debugger, otherwise you will always run into problems like this. Becoming better in coding is not so much about not making mistakes, but more about knowing how to detect and fix them and a debugger is made for exactly that.

Comment: Thank you very much, and yes i will play with it using debugger asap i can.

Comment: @Mac see also the last edit. Implementing a merge sort is good to practice on algorithms but you also should learn to use the available tools

Comment: I knew about std::sort, i was just trying to understand better how does that sorting  algorithm works, but still thank you.

Answer (score 1):

A quicksort using pointers does not need to pass the array name as a parameter. Example code:

```
void QuickSort(int *lo, int *hi)
{
int *i, *j;
int p, t;
    if(lo >= hi)
        return;
    p = *(lo + (hi-lo)/2);
    i = lo - 1;
    j = hi + 1;
    while (1){
        while (*(++i) < p);
        while (*(--j) > p);
            if (i >= j)
                break;
            t = *i;
            *i = *j;
            *j = t;
    }
    QuickSort(lo, j);
    QuickSort(j+1, hi);
}
```

The call to quick sort would be:

```
QuickSort(array, array+(sizeof(array)/sizeof(array[0]))-1);
```